# Tkinter listbox selecting empty elements

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox

```py
# creating the 2 listboxes
possible = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=root, text="Possible Reagents", font=font2, width=110)
possible.place(x=400, y=8)
possibleListbox = tkinter.Listbox(root, selectmode=tkinter.SINGLE, exportselection=False, width=15, height=10)
possibleListbox.place(x=400,y=30)
possibleScrollbar = tkinter.Scrollbar(root)
possibleScrollbar.place(x=493, y=30, height=164)
possibleListbox.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", possibleClicked)
possibleListbox.bind("<Double-Button-1>", possibleClicked)
possibleListbox.config(yscrollcommand=possibleScrollbar.set)
possibleScrollbar.config(command=possibleListbox.yview)

selected = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=root, text="Selected Reagents", font=font2, width=110)
selected.place(x=530, y=8)
selectedListbox = tkinter.Listbox(root, selectmode=tkinter.SINGLE, exportselection=False, width=15, height=10)
selectedListbox.place(x=530, y=30)
selectedScrollbar = tkinter.Scrollbar(root)
selectedScrollbar.place(x=623, y=30, height=164)
selectedListbox.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", selectedClicked)
selectedListbox.bind("<Double-Button-1>", selectedClicked)
selectedListbox.config(yscrollcommand=selectedScrollbar.set)
selectedScrollbar.config(command=selectedListbox.yview)

#functions for moving one element to the other listbox

def possibleClicked(stuff):
    global curselect
    if possibleListbox.curselection():
        curselect = possibleListbox.curselection()
    selectedItem = possibleListbox.get(curselect)
    possibleListbox.delete(curselect)
    selectedListbox.insert(tkinter.END, selectedItem)
def selectedClicked(stuff):
    global curselect
    if selectedListbox.curselection():
        curselect = selectedListbox.curselection()
    selectedItem = selectedListbox.get(curselect)
    selectedListbox.delete(curselect)
    possibleListbox.insert(tkinter.END, selectedItem)
```

For some reason, I'm able to select empty elements in both listboxes even though I didn't insert them?
Not sure whats causing this error, I've tried checking if the selected element is == "", but this causes another error.

See the gif below for a better explanation

[Gif of problem:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hRPed.gif)

Answer (score 0):

`Listbox.curselection()` is the *list* of the currently selected items.    To retrieve the first selected item, you must use `curselect = possibleListbox.curselection()[0]` .